# How to set scanning interval in metaio(unity package)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, intervals, metaio

I put in 100 targets in my APP that is developed by metaio(unity package). But the frame rate is very low. So I want to change the scanning interval from every frame to every 5 frames. Can any one tell me how to do it? Thx

Answer (score 0):

you should change the `MaxObjectsToDetectPerFrame` of the XML tracking configuration, see https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/documentation/tracking-config/optical-tracking/image-tracking/